# Mongoose: Find label in array and return matching documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my current Mongo DB, I have a simple Parts collection, with a Parent Children relationship, like the following:

```
{"partcode": "Parent1","children": ["Child1","Child2","Child3"]}

{"partcode": "Child1","label": ["label1"]}
{"partcode": "Child2","label": ["label1"]}
{"partcode": "Child3","label": ["label1"]}
```

In order to return the children of a partcode, I use the following Mongoose function:

```
PartSchema.static('getChildren', function(query, callback) {
  var self = this,
  self.findOne(query, {children: 1, _id: 0})
    .exec(function(err, doc) {
      return (self.find({
        "partcode": {
          "$in": doc.children
        }
      }, {_id: 0}, callback));
    });
});
```

This returns the following array:

```
[{"partcode": "Child1","label": ["label1"]},
{"partcode": "Child2","label": ["label1"]},
{"partcode": "Child3","label": ["label1"]}]
```

I'd like to implement a label system, whereby I can specify a label as a meta-child, and for the code to return all children matching that label.

```
{"partcode": "Parent1","children": ["*label1"]}
```

would return:

```
[{"partcode": "Child1","label": ["label1"]},
{"partcode": "Child2","label": ["label1"]},
{"partcode": "Child3","label": ["label1"]}]
```

I'll specify a label in the parent document's children field as starting with a special character (currently, I'm using '*', but happy to change that to something else if needs be).

Pseudocode:

1. find *Parent*
2. Get *Parent*'s **children** array
3. In array, if *child* starts with *label* character

   1. get array of all partcodes of parts that match *label* and
   2. substitute partcodes for label in **children** array
4. return **children** array

Children that aren't prefaced with a label character should also be returned.

Comment: you can use regular expressions in the $in statement. Something along the lines of `find({label: {$in: [/label1/]}}, callback)`
Make sure to add an index for the `label` field

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm okay with the detail around a find. I have created a label function that returns all objects with a specific label. What I'm unsure of is how best to structure it; that is, the broad strokes. I'm leaning towards an Aggregate pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work as follows:

```
PartSchema.static('getChildren', function(query, callback) {
  var self = this,
    children = [],
    labels = [];
  self.findOne(query, {children: 1, _id: 0})
    .exec(function(err, doc) {
      //find labels
      labels = _.filter(doc.children, obj => /^\*/.test(obj));
      //remove labels from children array
      children = _.difference(doc.children, labels);
      //remove label identifier '*'
      labels = _.map(labels, label => label.substring(1));
      self.find({
        vendor: vendor,
        $or: [{
          "partcode": {
            "$in": children
          }
        }, {
          "label": {
            "$in": labels
          }
        }]
      }, {_id: 0}, callback);
    });
});
```

I'd be interested in comments. Particularly around elegance, structure, convention, etc. Anything so poor form or ugly, it makes your eye tick?

Comment: do you really need a special character to differenciate? and apply filter and difference and also use map.. u can make it much simpler by just removing special character..

Comment: posted my own answer as an improvement

Answer (score 0):

Following up with [OP's self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834427/3556874),

You don't really need a special character(`*`) here to differentiate a label from a child field. This will also reduce your array operations used(`filter`, `difference`, `map`).

So suppose you don't have a special character for label, your collection would look like:

```
{"partcode": "Parent1","children": ["label1"]}
```

and

```
[{"partcode": "Child1","label": ["label1"]},
{"partcode": "Child2","label": ["label1"]},
{"partcode": "Child3","label": ["label1"]}]
```

So following code will give you the desired result:

```
PartSchema.static('getChildren', function(query, callback) {
  var self = this,
    children = [],
    labels = [];
  self.findOne(query, {children: 1, _id: 0})
    .exec(function(err, doc) {
// simply find for children in both `label` and `partcode` fields,
// using whole children array
          self.find({
            vendor: vendor,
            $or: [{
              "partcode": {
                "$in": doc.children
              }
            }, {
              "label": {
                "$in": doc.children
              }
            }]
          }, {_id: 0}, callback);
        });
    });
```

**Note**: This solution is applicable if `child` field in a `doc` is not a `label` field in another `doc` and vice versa.

Comment: Hi Naeem, thanks for your response. I'm afraid we do need a special character to differentiate between "labels" and "children" as there is a possibility of partcodes having the same name as labels.